# no suitable constructor exists to convert from "v8::Array *" to "v8::Local<v8::Array>"

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I am trying to cast the arguments passed to my C++ addon into arrays but I am running into the error in the title. This is my code:

```
#include "node.h"
#include "node_buffer.h"
#include "v8.h"

using namespace v8;
using namespace std;

namespace water{
    using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
    using v8::Isolate;
    using v8::Local;
    using v8::Object;
    using v8::String;
    using v8::Number;
    using v8::Value;
    using v8::Array;

    void water(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args)
    {
        if(args[0]->IsArray())
        {
           Local<Array> a = Array::Cast(*args[0]);
           Local<Array> b = Array::Cast(*args[1]);
        }
        args.GetReturnValue().Set(20);
    }
    }
```

This is my error `no suitable constructor exists to convert from “v8::Array *” to “v8::Local<v8::Array>”`

In other words, I am looking to pass in arrays to my method from a NodeJs program using node-gyp but I can't seem to do so.

Comment: `**Local<Array> a ` -- Do not put stars in the code to denote emphasis.  A star could easily be confused for a pointer dereference, multiplication, or other places where asterisks are used in the code.  Second, this looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2):

Reading [the documentation](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-4.8/de/deb/classv8_1_1_local.html), I think it should be

```
Local<Array> a = args[0].As<Array>();
```